# ntdll.dll access violation error

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, upgrade, dll, x86

we did an in-place upgrade of a `windows 2003 server` to `windows 2008 server.` After the upgrade, couple of windows services stopped working. The error i am getting in the event viewer looks like this:

> Faulting application someservice.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp
>   0x38f21f27, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.19346, time
>   stamp 0x55024174, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x00066439,
>   process id 0x10e8, application start time 0x01d0afd9a7dee788.

What this application does is, it reads a text file and parses the output.

In the application log, i can see it got to the file but before it can read, it crashed. I do not have source code for this application. May be it fails to open the file.

This application works fine on `Windows 2003 Server`.

I tried to create dump files but it did not generate any.

When i run `"cmd"` from `Run` menu and try to run `chkdsk` or `scandisk`, it throws me an error saying these `commands requires DOS 6.0 or higher`. But when i open `Command.com` from `C:\Windows\System32` folder and run these commands, they work just fine.

I ran `chkdsk, scandisk, sfc` but none of this options have helped me fix the issue.

I am running this on `Windows Server 2008 SP2` with all the `Windows Updates` installed.

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.

More details:

When i run `"cmd"` from the `Run` prompt, it shows `C:\Users\User0000004`. For 2003 servers, it used to show `C:\Users\<myloginusername>`. When i checked `c:\users` folder, all the folders that should have previously logged in user names were renamed to `User000001, User0000002, User0000003` etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Dumb Question #1:** Have you turned off UAC?

More often than not this causes issues with applications that "Worked fine in 2003".

**Dumb Question #2:** Have you tried ProcMon to figure out *why* it's crashing?

"May be it fails to open the file.": I think you nailed it here (either file or port related would be my guess), procmon will help you verify the issue. Setup the filter by process name, then look for `ACCESS_DENIED` or other similar errors while trying to execute the application.

Download [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) (it's free, and supported by Microsoft)

Comment: Yes. UAC is disabled. I used ProcMon but no access denied error. I used ProcessExplorer and paused it when the service appeared but no file handle open. i used Debug Diagnostics Tool to generate the dump but it did not generate any. It generated a trace file and had no errors in it.

Comment: "no file handle open" ... I assume you are expecting one then? This is a bit of a hard question to answer because the service code you are asking about was written only for you. I wonder if system libraries from 2003 were  compiled in directly ... anyway, I don't think anyone will really be able to help apart from the person that wrote the code. Try expanding the procmon filter to include the ntdll.dll errors as well.